# Replacing &qout; with " when writing to text file with python

Tags: python, string

I am reading a list of column names from a text file and then using those to render an sql template using pystache, then writing rendered template to an sql file. The problem is occasionally the column name will have a colon thus needing to be surrounded by double quotes in the query.

Example of column names text file:

```
column1
"column2:extra"
column3
```

I am running into a problem where the double quotes are getting replaced by &*quot*; in the output file. I have tried using

```
#read in column names
with open(attrs_file, 'r') as fields:
    attrs = fields.read().splitlines()

...

with open(sql_in, 'r') as sql:
    data = sql.read()
    data = pystache.render(data, {'replace':new})

with open(sql_out, 'wb') as sql:
    data = data.replace('&qout;', '"')
    #data = data.replace('&qout;', "\"")
    sql.write(data)
```

The replace method has not worked, and I would rather not have to do post-processing to search and replace and &qout; after creating the file. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I see you are using pystache, presumably to substitute the value of the global variable `new` to construct an appropriate SQL query string. Please note that unless the value of `new` has been extensively vetted you leave yourself open to SQL injection vulnerabilities (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

If you are using the Python DB API there are ways to parameterize queries that don't open up such vulnerabilities, but you don't address that part of your project. I'd suggest `pystache` is not what you need.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the heads up. This is just a local postgres database to aid in processing some spatial data. The sql file that is generated is then ran as part of a shell script. This may deviate from original question, but are there better methods for building sql files where the field names will vary?

Comment: Well you could look inside the guts of one of the many packages that support the Python DBAPI, but thanks for reminding me that you can't parameterize the structural elements such as tables and columns in SQL queries (because this would invalidate the SQL interpreter's ability to re-use a prepared query, I believe).

So you are off the hook for constructing your own statements. But you might want to consider using something as simpler than pystacheto expand your template (which apparently has the quotes in it already). Consider just using a Python dictionary and %(name)s interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` doesn't modify the string in-place, it returns a new string instance with the desired changes. You should assign the returned value to something.

```
data = data.replace('&qout;', '"')
```

Comment: Err.. thanks for that. Still does not correct the final output though.

Comment: I see you edited your code to have `date = data.replace('&qout;', '"')`. That `date` should be `data`.